# Binding to Listpickerflyout

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have been trying to bind listpickerflyout to some data and it doesn't seem to display the data when I debug. 
Here is the XAML Code:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App6"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:ViewModel="using:App6.ViewModel"
xmlns:Model="using:App6.Model"
x:Class="App6.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Button Margin="10,0,0,583" Width="313">
        <Button.Flyout>
            <ListPickerFlyout ItemsSource="{Binding Language.Name}"/>
        </Button.Flyout>

        <Button.DataContext>
            <Model:Language/>
        </Button.DataContext>

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

And the other codes MVVM model:

```
namespace App6.Model
{
    public class Language
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

viewmodel:

```
namespace App6.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public Language Language { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Language = new Language
            {
                Name = "English",
                id = 1
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an object of type "Language" to the datacontext of the button. Therefore the Binding Path is wrong as "Language" does not have a property "Language".

You should create an instance of your viewmodel and assign it to the datacontext of the window. No assignment on the button.

Comment: Ok With my code I am able to bind to listview but I am unable to bind to listpickerflyout... I will be glad if someone show me a simple procedure on how to bind to listpicker. my viewmodel code and model code seems to be ok. not the one above though because I make changes to it and was able to bind to listview.